# google-maps-api-3 ruby on rails

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am getting the following error

**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google**

when I am rendering a page the first time which should display the google maps. The first part of the page is shown correctly, but at the bottom the entire div with the map is missing. After click on refresh the page is rendered correctly. This error is the same in dev and prod and shows up for page in the application containing a google map. Don't know how to fix it. 
Here are more details about the error from the Safari's console:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new google.maps.OverlayView()')
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new google.maps.OverlayView')
```

Below is the code of one of this pages generating the errors above.

```
    <% provide(:title, 'Current TBMs Location and Statistics') %>
    <% if signed_in? %>
        <h3>TBMs location and statistics - Today's date: <%=@current_date%></h3>
        <div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <%= link_to "Daily Progress", progresstable_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
                <%= link_to "Daily Stats", tbms_stats_table_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <%= "Today's: " %>
                <%= link_to "Schedule", schedules_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
                <%= link_to "Readings List", all_readings_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br></br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h5>
                <%= "TBM ID: " %>
                <%= @tbms_progress_W.tbm_id %>
                <%= "aka TBM1 or 26900"%>
                </h5>
                <%= "Last Date: " %>
                <%= @tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
                <%= "Max Station: " %>
                <%= number_with_precision @tbm_w_location, precision: 2 %>
                <%= "Status: " %>
                <%= @tbms_progress_W.tbm_status %>
                <%= "Since: " %>
                <%= @tbm_w_days_since %>
                </br>
                <%= "Days total: " %>
                <%= @tbm_w_days_since_commissioned %>
                <%= "Days working: "%>
                <%= @tbm_w_working_days %>
                <%= "Days stopped: " %>
                <%= @tbm_w_stopped_days %>

                <%= "Located between: " %>
                <% if @smp_w_after.present? %>
                    <%= @smp_w_after.smp_id %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= " and: " %>
                <% if @smp_w_before.present? %>
                    <%= @smp_w_before.smp_id %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                </br>
                <%= "Total excavated: " %>
                <% if @tbm_w_location.present? %>
                    <%= @tbm_w_location - @tbms_W_initial.max_station %> <%="m"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= "Excavation speed: " %>
                <% if @tbm_w_location.present? %>
                    <%= number_with_precision (@tbm_w_location - @tbms_W_initial.max_station) / @tbm_w_working_days, precision: 2 %> <%="m/day"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= "Excavated since yesterday cut off time: " %>
                <% if @tbm_w_location.present? %>
                    <%= @tbm_w_location - @tbms_progress_W2.max_station %> <%="m"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                </br>
                <%= "Average distance excavated in the previous 24 hours: " %>
                <% if @tbm_w_location.present? %>
                    <%= @tbms_progress_W2.max_station - @tbms_progress_W1.max_station %> <%="m"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <% if @tbm_w_lat == nil or @tbm_w_lon == nil %>
                    </br>
                    <%= "TBM latitude and longitude cannot be calculated, missing near SMP northing and easting" %>
                    </br>
                    <%= "TBM approximate address: not available" %>
                <% else %>
                    </br>
                    <%= "Latitude: " %>
                    <%= number_with_precision @tbm_w_lat, precision: 6 %>
                    <%= " Longitude: " %>
                    <%= number_with_precision @tbm_w_lon, precision: 6 %>
                    <%= "Address: " %>
                    <% if @tbm_w_result.empty? %>
                        <%= "Cannot calculate TBM W address, Geocoder unavailable" %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= @tbm_w_result[0].address %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>

                <% if @current_date != @tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
                    <h6 class="error-message">
                        <%= "Today's location for TBM W is not loaded" %>
                        <%= " Last TBM W recorded date was: " %>
                        <%=@tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
                    </h6>
                <% end %>

                <h6> SMPs ahead of the current TBM W location: </h6>
                <% if @tbm_w_location.present? and @smps_w_ahead.present? %>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <%= "First line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_w_ahead[0].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[0].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[1].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[1].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%= "Second line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_w_ahead[2].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[2].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[3].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[3].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%= "Third line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_w_ahead[4].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[4].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[5].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[5].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%= "Fourth line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_w_ahead[6].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[6].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[7].smp_id %> <%= @smps_w_ahead[7].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>

                <h5>
                <%= "TBM ID: " %>
                <%= @tbms_progress_E.tbm_id %>
                <%= "aka TBM2 or 27000"%>
                </h5>
                <%= "Last Date: " %>
                <%= @tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
                <%= "Max Station: " %>
                <%= number_with_precision @tbm_e_location, precision: 2 %>
                <%= "Status: " %>
                <%= @tbms_progress_E.tbm_status %>
                <%= "Since: " %>
                <%= @tbm_e_days_since %>
                </br>
                <%= "Days total: " %>
                <%= @tbm_e_days_since_commissioned %>
                <%= "Days working: "%>
                <%= @tbm_e_working_days %>
                <%= "Days stopped: " %>
                <%= @tbm_e_stopped_days %>

                <%= "Located between: " %>
                <% if @smp_e_after.present? %>
                    <%= @smp_e_after.smp_id %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= " and: " %>
                <% if @smp_e_before.present? %>
                    <%= @smp_e_before.smp_id %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                </br>
                <%= "Total excavated: " %>
                <% if @tbm_e_location.present? %>
                    <%= @tbm_e_location - @tbms_E_initial.max_station %> <%="m"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= "Excavation speed: " %>
                <% if @tbm_e_location.present? %>
                    <%= number_with_precision (@tbm_e_location - @tbms_E_initial.max_station) / @tbm_e_working_days, precision: 2 %> <%="m/day"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= "Excavated since yesterday cut off time: " %>
                <% if @tbm_e_location.present? %>
                    <%= @tbm_e_location - @tbms_progress_E2.max_station %> <%="m"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                </br>
                <%= "Average distance excavated in the previous 24 hours: " %>
                <% if @tbm_e_location.present? %>
                    <%= @tbms_progress_E2.max_station - @tbms_progress_E1.max_station %> <%="m"%>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
                <% if @tbm_e_lat == nil or @tbm_e_lon == nil %>
                    </br>
                    <%= "TBM latitude and longitude cannot be calculated, missing near SMP northing and easting" %>
                    </br>
                    <%= "TBM approximate address: not available" %>
                <% else %>
                    </br>
                    <%= "Latitude: " %>
                    <%= number_with_precision @tbm_e_lat, precision: 6 %>
                    <%= " Longitude: " %>
                    <%= number_with_precision @tbm_e_lon, precision: 6 %>
                     <%= "Address: " %>
                    <% if @tbm_e_result.empty? %>
                        <%= "Cannot calculate TBM E address, Geocoder unavailable" %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= @tbm_e_result[0].address %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>

                <% if @current_date != @tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
                    <h6 class="error-message">
                        <%= "Today's location for TBM E is not loaded" %>
                        <%= " Last TBM E recorded date was: " %>
                        <%=@tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
                    </h6>
                <% end %>

                <h6> SMPs ahead of the current TBM E location: </h6>
                <% if @tbm_e_location.present? and @smps_e_ahead.present? %>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <%= "First line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_e_ahead[0].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[0].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[1].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[1].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%= "Second line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_e_ahead[2].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[2].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[3].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[3].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%= "Third line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_e_ahead[4].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[4].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[5].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[5].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <%= "Fourth line: " %>
                            <%= @smps_e_ahead[6].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[6].final_inst_status %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[7].smp_id %> <%= @smps_e_ahead[7].final_inst_status %>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                <% else %>
                    <%= "Unknown" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style='width: 800px;'>
            <div id="map" style='width: 920px; height: 500px;'></div>
        </div>

    <% else %>
        <%= render 'instruments/unsigned' %>
    <% end %>

    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        buildMap (<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    </script>
```

Comment: From the information you posted in [v3 Issue 6995](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6995) the problem appears to be in the `buildMap` function.Without being able to see the live page, however, this is very difficult to debug. The error suggests that code is executing before the Maps API is loaded, but without seeing how the page actually loads all of its code (and the order in which it executes), there's not much more we can figure out.

Comment: Hello Brendan, I created an account for you in the application. Please use guest@anywhere.com as ID and the password is password. It is a read only account so no worries about damaging anything there. The application URL is: https://expmonitor.herokuapp.com . If you use Safari and activate the console you will see the errors first time you use any of the index pages. You can start from the main menu with TBMs | Current Location or any menu item from Instruments, i.e. SMPs, MPBXes,etc. Initially at the bottom an empty rectangle is shown. After refresh all maps are shown correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately the page is not currently loading for me. Instead I get a 503 Service Unavailable response and then an Application Error Page asking me to try again in a few moments.

Comment: Please try again, the web site was down for a little while, for maintenance probably the same time you attempted. It is up again and working since this morning at 7:00am Eastern Time. Thank you and please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: put all links refs to css and js in application.html.erb, after turbolinks and good by errors. Seems that browsers need to cache all of this before page x in the app is due for render.